# DNS only accepts www nothing else

Tags: domain-name-system

My domain is with GoDaddy and im aware they have an issue with CNAME entries including @.

IS there a way i can resolve this issue?

What im trying to achieve is having the domain CNAME entries point to my DDNS so if ever i change my ip for whatever reason i curl back there to update it.

Now the problem i always had this. when i go to www.domain.ca it works just fine. but when i put in domain.ca in incognito or try to ping it it cant resolve saying it cant find the ip/hostname.

I have 2 entries for CNAME and no A record. one with * and www pointing to the same DDNS. Is this the correct way to put in a wildcard?

My settings in nginx are as follows.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ;
    root /home/web/wordpress/;
    index index.php;
    server_name LANIP domain.ca www.domain.ca DDNS.ddns.net;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.ca/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.ca/privkey.pem;
    access_log /home/web/wordpress/access.log;
    error_log /home/web/wordpress/error.log notice;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Let me know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: No, this is not possible. A `CNAME` replaces  other record types including the `NS` records. That's why you can never use it at the apex of a domain.

Comment: so long story short its not possible? how can i resolve this issue then?

Comment: Correct. You can solve it but not making it an issue. Have e.g. some static IP server to redirect the naked domain to a subdomain.

Comment: could you provide an example? I want to be sure im following the right train of thought.

Comment: GoDaddy even has a service for URL redirection: https://www.godaddy.com/help/create-url-redirects-5120:

Comment: i dont have godaddy web hosting. i only use it for domain services. I use my own raspberry pi with nginx to do my hosting.

Comment: Why not use a DDNS client to perform the updates for you? If not running on your computer/server then on your router or firewall, most of which support DDNS.

Comment: The problem is with your DNS zone, not with your nginx configuration. Please post your DNS settings.

Comment: what DDNS client software do you recommend? and my dns just has CNAME entries pointing to my DDNS